# Undefined variable on POST

Tags: php, variables, post, indexing, undefined

I looked trough your pages and fixed my undefined index on username and password but now I get undefined variable. I had more code but decided to simplify it for the sake of testing and just echo it to see if anything changes and it doesn't.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uname = isset($_POST['username']);             
$pass = isset($_POST['password']); 
}

echo $uname;
echo $password;
?>
```

I get this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\8\login.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\8\login.php on
>   line 8

I do not really understand what's wrong here. If needed here is my form page html.

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="login.php">
<div id="loginon">
<label for="username" style="color:#0F0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" >Username: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<br  />
<br  />

<label for="password"  style="color:#0F0; size:auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Password: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> 
<br />
<br />
<input type="image" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/G/4/v/K/E/submit-hi.png" border="0" width="180px" height="80px" alt="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**
The further problem is connected to this so I think I am allowed to post it here.

```
if($username == "pikachu" || "cloud") {
    $ucheck = "dobar";
} else {
    $ucheck = "los";
}

if ($password == "123123" || "132132") {
    $pcheck = "topar";
} else {
    $pcheck = "losh";
}

if($ucheck == "dobar" && $pcheck == "topar") {
    echo "Najjaci si!";

}

elseif ($ucheck == "dobar" && $pcheck == "losh") {
    echo "Wimp.";
} elseif ($ucheck == "los" && $pcheck == "topar") {
    echo "Fish.";
}
```

The problem is that it always echoes out "Najjaci si" no matter what I type in the previous form. Any ideas?

Comment: declare `$uname = $pass ="";` before condition

Comment: There is no `input` with name `submit`.

Comment: If I do that, I get "Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\8\login.php on line 9"

Comment: @victiMusPrime check variable `$pass` and `$password`...you are using two different variable

Comment: I get a blank page now, which means that the form data doesn't come to the page. Jonas m has the solution but thank you all for the effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the variable decleration inside a logic (If), there is a chance that the variables are not set at all. 
Try this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $uname = isset($_POST['username']);             
  $pass = isset($_POST['password']); 

  echo $uname;
  echo $pass;
} else {
  echo "No submit detected!";
}


?>
```

It also doesen't look like if you have an actual element named submit.
Try adding this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send my form" />
```

Now, your form contains an element named "submit" which will be send as a post parameter when the form is submitted.

I myself, in need of a framework, like doing like this:

```
$username = ( isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != "" ? $_POST["username"] : false );
$password = ( isset($_POST["password"]) && $_POST["password"] != "" ? $_POST["password"] : false );

if( !$username === false && !$password === false )
{
    echo $username . " <br /> " . $password;
} else {
    echo "No! :) ";
}
```

Comment: It echoes "No submit detected!"

Comment: Because you need to add a submit-button to your html form. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Oooooh, so it was the submit button that was causing the whole problem?
Thanks, I have it all sorted out now. :)

Comment: Yes it was. Because you were only setting the variables, if the key "submit" was set in the POST array. It were not, since nothing with the name "submit" were posted :)

Comment: You are writing: if($username == "pikachu" || "cloud")  It should be if($username == "pikachu" || $username == "cloud")  You need the variable you want to check up against on all "OR's"/"Ands"

Comment: Jonas m tried this now, It doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` will check that variable is `set` or `not` and pass value in `0` or `1`. So over here you need to do as

```
$uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';             
$pass = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\8\login.php on line 8

Its because you were echoing `$password` instead of `$pass`

**Edited**

Do it as

```
$uname = '';
$pass = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uname = isset($_POST['username']);             
$pass = isset($_POST['password']); 
}

echo $uname;
echo $pass;
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after trying your fix. Any other clues?

Comment: Check first is it getting within `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In form**

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="login.php">
    <div id="loginon">
        <label for="username" style="color:#0F0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" >Username: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <br  />
        <br  />

        <label for="password"  style="color:#0F0; size:auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Password: &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

**In login.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
    }

    echo $uname;
    echo $pass;
?>
```